# Wordpress loads wrong template with URL parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, parameters, google-ads-api

I have a strange problem with my site. It is a wordpress site working for a while now, and our company started some Adwords campaigns to boost views. Google Adwords adds a gclid parameter to the URL when clicked, and the site is loading another template (the default post template) instead of the template for the homepage.

I'd like to know, where to start searching for the faulthy parts? Any ideas?

Thanks!

PS: Not just the gclid parameter does this, but all other fake parameters too. Strange thing is that only the homepage does this, the other pages with structured URL-s are not doing so. The site uses Visual Composer plugin, if it is important. We tried to solve the problem by .htaccess file, but the redirect causes an error in Analytics tracking of Adwords visitors, so it is not a solution.

Comment: Can you share URL example or your site URL?

Comment: Are you using a static front page or a blog home page? If it's a static home page did you used the _front-page.php_ file for your home template?

Comment: I think it is a static page, marked as Front page. It is built with Visual Composer plugin. In my theme folder there is no front-page.php file.

Comment: I have a hint about the problem - the site loads the default page.php with the default variable values when it receives a permalink which hasn't got predefined variable values for the layout template. The theme does not know which layout variable value is correct for the page, because the homepage permalink is resolved by wordpress itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, we found a solution!

The theme lacked the front-page.php template for the homepage (read more about wordpress template structure!), so I created it with the correct template HTML code according to the correct layout variable values, and it loads just fine. The URL parameters are not affecting the permalink structure anymore, because now we have a template for the homepage too.

This is better than doing hours of research for redirect- or permalink method workarounds...

Comment: thanks you! this did the trick ! I simply copied page.php to front-page.php and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

if everything fails please use template_redirect hook to load any template you want... [template_redirect hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)

Also you have to send a 200 OK header there if you simply load file and exit.